# Get monthly average in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following time series:

```
        Date        Value
0       2006-01-03  18
1       2006-01-04  12
2       2006-01-05  11
3       2006-01-06  10
4       2006-01-09  22
...     ...     ...
3510    2019-12-23  47
3511    2019-12-24  46
3512    2019-12-26  35
3513    2019-12-27  35
3514    2019-12-30  28
```

I want to calculate the average values per month. So the pseudocode for each month is as follows:

1. Sum all the values for each day present in that month
2. Divide by the number of days with data for that month.

The desired output would be something similar to:

```
        Date        Value
0       2006-01     17.45
1       2006-02     18.23
2       2006-04     16.79
3       2006-05     17.98
...     ...     ...
166     2019-11     37.89
167     2019-12     36.34
```

I have tried this without success:

```
data = data.set_index('Date')
data.resample('M')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-435afe449f1f> in <module>
     47 data = pd.DataFrame(dataList, columns=('Date', 'Value'))
     48 data = data.set_index('Date')
---> 49 data.resample('M')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can convert your datetime column into a `PeriodIndex` on monthly frequency, then take the mean using `GroupBy.mean`:

```
df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq="M"))['Value'].mean()
    
Date
2006-01    14.6
2019-12    38.2
Freq: M, Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq="M"))['Value'].mean().reset_index()

      Date  Value
0  2006-01   14.6
1  2019-12   38.2
```

One caveat of this approach is that missing months are not shown. If that's important, use `set_index` and `resample.mean` in the same way.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think days_in_month takes into consideration all natural days in a particular month, but I do not have data for every day

Comment: @M.E. apologies, misunderstood the question. Please see the edit here.

Answer (score 10):

You could try something like this, which even does not require the change on the index:

`data_month = data.resample('M', on='Date').mean()`

Please, note that the resample itself does not do the trick by itself. The `.mean()` is required.

More on the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) :)

Comment: I try that and I get: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: ok, then please make sure that your 'Date' column is of type Datetime. Something like `data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)`

Comment: @cs95 actually I want to divide by the number of rows per month, not by the natural days of the month (in case that it is not clear in the original question)

Comment: I chosed @cs95 answer but this one is actually pretty valid and I am bookmarking it as I find it very useful