# Calculate daily and monthly averages for categories in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have the following dataframe

```
date        sales      cat
29/4/2022   2          a
30/4/2022   5          a
30/4/2022   1          b
1/5/2022    1          a
1/5/2022    8          b 
1/5/2022    4          c
1/6/2022    7          a
1/6/2022    9          b
1/6/2022    5          c
```

I want to calculate the daily mean and the monthly mean of sales for each `cat`.
The end dataframe should look like this

```
    date        sales      cat    daily_avg    monthly_avg
    29/4/2022   2          a     2            2
    30/4/2022   5          a     3.5          7
    30/4/2022   1          b     1            1
    1/5/2022    1          a     2.67         4
    1/5/2022    8          b     4.5          4.5
    1/5/2022    4          c     4            4
    1/6/2022    7          a     0.45         5
    1/6/2022    9          b     0.56         6
    1/6/2022    5          c     0.29         4.5
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: how do you calculate your mounthly avg ? shouldn't it be (5+2)/2 = 3.5 in the second row ?

Comment: i did (5+2)/1 since the sales were on the same month

Answer (score 0):

USE-

```
#Monthly Average
df['monthly_avg'] = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq="M"))['Value'].mean()

#Daily Average
df['daily_avg'] = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq="D"))['Value'].mean()
```

`This is untested code,always share reproducible code for test datasets.`

Ref link- [Get monthly average in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471540/get-monthly-average-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas `expanding` windowing operations: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html

Btw your monthly average is not right (for example April should be 7/2 for cat a and 1/1 for cat b).

Something like this would count daily average:

```
df.groupBy(['date', 'cat']).expanding().avg()
```

For monthly create column containing just month and year and do similar thing.

Comment: but i want the average for each `cat`. The average should be different depending on when they first appear on the data set. for `a` in april there was 7 sales so monthly average 7/1=7

Comment: so if you want that use .rolling() instead of .expanding() as per docs suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('29/4/2022 ', periods=9, freq='D')
sales = [2, 5, 1, 1, 8, 4, 7, 9, 5]
cat = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'sales': sales, 'cat': cat})
df['day'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('D').astype(str) + 
df['cat'].astype(str)
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M').astype(str) + 
df['cat'].astype(str)

pivot_D = df.pivot_table(index='day', aggfunc={'sales': np.average})
pivot_D = pd.DataFrame(pivot_D)
pivot_M = df.pivot_table(index='month', aggfunc={'sales': np.average})
pivot_M = pd.DataFrame(pivot_M)

pivot_D_df_v = pd.merge(df, pivot_D, on='day', how='left')
pivot_D_df_v = pd.DataFrame(pivot_D_df_v)
pivot_D_df_v = pd.merge(pivot_D_df_v, pivot_M, on='month', how='left')
pivot_D_df_v = pd.DataFrame(pivot_D_df_v)

pivot_D_df_v.columns = pivot_D_df_v.columns.str.replace('sales_y',     'daily_avg')
pivot_D_df_v.columns = pivot_D_df_v.columns.str.replace('sales_x', 'sale')
pivot_D_df_v.columns = pivot_D_df_v.columns.str.replace('sales', 'monthly_avg')

pivot_D_df_v.drop(['day', 'month'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(pivot_D_df_v)
```

1. Create an helper column for days and months.
2. Pivot the created columns.
3. Combine, merge with the main base.
4. Renaming columns (automatically assigned in the process)
5. Delete the helper columns.